# Ubuntu keyboard fails for root user

Tags: 16.04, command-line, keyboard, root

I can't use terminal based solutions; the system keyboard works great from guest, but many applications are restricted for guest login, eg: terminal, update, etc. since I found my second computer died , possibly a power hit, 
I put the windows drive from that computer in the Ubuntu machine and put Ubuntu on a 3rd hard drive, still if I boot up the other drive keyboard will not function, but the new install works good, have no access to anything on the old ubuntu install drive,

How can I access my system?

Comment: can you log in as a different user and use sudo or su? there should be more than just root and guest account....

Comment: tried  using a screen keyboard , that did not work, tried all the fixes I could find posted, but every attempt was blocked, and could not get terminal from Guest to work in any way,

Comment: when you installed ubuntu, it required you to create a user.  Log in with that username and password, (for example "denis") and then use sudo... and when it asks for a password, enter the password for "denis"

Comment: Logged in as guest, but even with Sudo  it never asked for password just said blocked ,  tried to determine how to put in password but nothing,  at this time if I could find out how to access the old hard drive it would be good, but better would be if I could access the information off the other computer that died it was running windows 7.

Comment: You cannot sudo with guest account.... guest account is a super restricted login. you need to log in with the USER YOU CREATED when you installed Ubuntu. don't try to do anything with guest account except surf the internet.

Comment: there are only 2 accounts guest and Denis the keyboard will not work with my account only guest, sudo works in guest but has no access to anything, the problem is what ever is turning off the keyboard, needs corrected but with no access to any form of keyboard how can that be done,

Comment: OK, so keyboard doesn't work as root or as denis user, ONLY as guest? what if from the login screen you hit ctrl+alt+f1 and try to login as denis there?